# Hyperlinks in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, hyperlink

I'm a novice SharePoint user and am trying to re-build a 2007 SharePoint site in 2010.

Within the 2007 site, I had 'Content Editor Web Parts' where certain words hyperlinked off to documents or webpages.

How do I replicate this function within SharePoint 2010? I've added the Content Editor web part but don't appear to have the same functionality to make specific words hyperlinks.

If anyone can explain this in laments terms it would be very much appreciated.

N.B - i'm re-building the site using Rich Text Editing rather than HTML code given my lack of technical background.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by selecting the word you want to turn into a hyperlink and then pressing CTRL + K. This will open the hyperlink box.

Alternatively, the ribbon should contain a section for Editing Tools with an Insert tab, this tab should contain Link. Select the text you want to link and then click this and you'll be given some options.